# How to insert a row and ignore only UNIQUE contraint errors, without using SELECT

Tags: php, database, exception, pdo, unique-constraint

I have a table with a column that must have UNIQUE values (but it could be also a multiple-column UNIQUE index, the problem is the same). In my PHP script I have to insert a row in that table.

I'm searching for a way, not MySQL-specific, to exit the PHP script if there's a problem, and the problem is **not** a violation of a UNIQUE constraint. To make things more easy I don't want to use a SELECT query before :D

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
try
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($someinsertquery);
    $stmt->bindParam(':somecol', $somecol);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $errcode = $e->getCode();

    if (! ($e->getCode() === '23000'))
    {
        echo 'Error inserting into db: ' . $e->getMessage();
        var_dump($e->getTrace());

        exit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this way I miss also errors related to foreign keys. I think it's okay if I can't have foreign keys problems inserting a new row, but what if I'll change the table in future? I could use

```
PDOStatement::errorInfo[1]
```

but it is a [driver specific error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php). The same with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a database-agnostic way to trap SQL errors.

The SQL standards define SQLSTATE as a two-character class followed by a three-character subclass. Some two-character classes are defined by the standards; others are defined by the implementation.

The standards define the two-character class '23' as "integrity constraint violation". They define only one subclass for '23'. It's '001', which means "restrict violation".  But implementations vary. Although MySQL apparently defines only '23000', [PostgreSQL defines at least six different subclasses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html) for '23'. (PostgreSQL subclasses distinguish foreign key violations from unique violations.)

So it appears that the *only* way to know what MySQL means by SQLSTATE '23000' is to look at the [MySQL error code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html). Error 1022 means "duplicate key"; 1216 and 1217 have to do with foreign key constraints.

It might be useful to look at the source code for various database "connectors" to see how *they're* implemented. The [php source code](http://php.net/git.php) is online. (I'd expect that to include PDO.)  So is [ruby's ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord).

Comment: Yes, but I exit the script if the error code is not equal to '23000'. I'm searching for a way, not MySQL-specific, to exit the script only if there's a problem and the problem is not a UNIQUE constraint is violated.

Comment: Apart the disk full, I don't really know what should my script do in such cases... and anyway this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer. I seem to be having a brain-free day today.  I'll shut up now.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful to know (there's very little about SQLSTATE on the web). I think I'll abandon the exception catch and adopt the @YourCommonSense solution, since on a second thought it allows me to not commit immediately the query. It's a pity that databases seem to not have a detailed and common error handling.

Answer (score 2):

```
$someinsertquery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table SET somecol=?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($someinsertquery);
$stmt->execute(array(($somecol)));
if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
    //everything is okay
}
```

Please note the all this try..catch..echo..exit stuff is omitted intentionally, as it is totally useless here.

Comment: The problem is I want to be sure the error is caused by a violation of a UNIQUE constraint. With my code I can miss some other constraint violation. With your code _all_ the errors are ignored.

Comment: How's that? define "ignored"? which one for example?

Comment: Well, see this post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update . I can use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE", but as for errorInfo this is MySQL specific.

Comment: I don't understand what does on duplicate to do here. Do you see any *certain* problem with this code?

Comment: I must admit I misunderstood what INSERT IGNORE do exactly... I thought it ignored foreign key constraints as well. It works and it's a good solution. Unfortunately it's only for MySQL... I was searching for a generic solution, but I'm starting to think there's not such a solution. Maybe the best solution is to do a function that, given the database, gives you the error code the database uses to identify unique constraints violations.

Answer (score 0):

It's either that or do a select prior to insert to see if there will be a collision on any unique indexes.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if that error code means I'm violating some UNIQUE constraints _only_. If I do a SELECT I'll be sure, but I'd prefer to catch the exception.

Comment: you can be guaranteed that is at least the problem. It only responds with a single error so if there are other things wrong with the request you wouldn't know