# PDO Transaction: how to know which queries caused an error?

Tags: php, database, exception, pdo, transactions

I'm using PDO inside a PHP script to do SQL queries. I want to do a transaction with more than one query and catch the errors. The code is like this:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO(...);
    $dbh-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch
{
    ...
}

$query1 = 'DO some QUERY';
$query2 = 'DO other QUERY';

try
{
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $dbh->exec($query1);
    $dbh->exec($query2);
    $dbh->commit();
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

How can I know which query caused the error? I want to do this because I want to ignore a duplicate key error for the first query but not for the second one, without using SELECT (see also [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696102/how-to-insert-a-row-and-ignore-only-unique-contraint-errors-without-using-selec) about UNIQUE error handling).

Comment: Use two different try-catch blocks?

Comment: @user1615903: that's what I'm doing now, but I would use transactions to speed up queries.

Comment: How does two try-catch blocks prevent you from using transactions?

Comment: you can use serveral try catch blocks and print message in catch() block and throw your own exception to be caught in the other block where you rollback() your transaction

Comment: @user1615903: well, you're right... I supposed it couldn't work because my last SQL error was originated by execute().

Comment: @Robert: yes you're right, read also my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    try
    {
       $dbh->exec($query1);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        throw new MyNewExtendedPdoException('first query exception'); // or just simply rollback + message
    }

    try
    {
        $dbh->exec($query2);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        throw new MyNewExtendedPdoException('2nd query exception');// or just simply rollback + message
    }

    $dbh->commit();
}
catch (MyNewExtendedPdoException $ex)
{
   $dbh->rollBack();
   echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

it can be done on various ways that is one of this way. You don't have to create your own exception class you can rollback your transaction in every try catch {} block then it will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only running a few queries - the SQL error will normally tell you what the error is (if you use `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. The solution I used was to create an array of all my queries and then outputted them in the Rollback section - it should be obvious from the error message and the queries you've got where the error lies. If you have large or lots of queries then this may be a bit much.